# Is Zurb Foundation better than Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

In what ways does Zurb Foundation give more functionality or features than Bootstrap?

Comment: Very subjective question. Opinions differ based on use case. You should try both and see which one best suites your use case. And This has nothing to do with `ruby-on-rails`. You can remove that tag

Comment: here is an excellent comparison... http://responsive.vermilion.com/compare.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This article](http://www.zingdesign.com/bootstrap-3-vs-foundation-4-feature-lineup/) has a nice summary of the differences. Straight from that article:

> Despite Foundation being able to boast more features, I would say the
>   two frameworks are now pretty much on par. Bootstrap 3 is moving more
>   towards an all-in-one development environment. Whereas Foundation
>   offers more in the way of interactive components for rapidly building
>   feature-rich apps and websites. They both look really clean, they’re
>   easy to customise and they’ll speed up the development process
>   enormously. So it really comes down to what suits you!

List of foundation 4 only features:

- Centered columns
- Block grid
- Form validation
- Gutter-free rows
- Native Sass support
- Pricing tables
- Right-to-left support
- Video scaling
- Website tour